# Using LIKE to compare two columns in SPARK SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, wso2-das

I have two SPARK SQL Tables as follows,

> Table 1

```
email           |  client_ip    |  travelling_method | travelling_code
person1@abc.com |203.22.22.22   | Car                | car001
person1@abc.com |203.22.22.22   | Jeep               | jeep001
```

> Table 2

```
email           |  client_ip    |  account_type | trav_code
person1@abc.com |203.22.22.22   | true          | car
person1@abc.com |203.22.22.22   | false         | jeep
```

> My query is as follows,

```
SELECT table1.email, table1.client_ip, table1.travelling_method, table1.travelling_code, table2.account_type FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email AND table1.client_ip = table2.client_ip AND table1.travelling_code LIKE CONCAT('%' ,table2.trav_code, '%') WHERE table1.email = 'person1@abc.com';
```

I wrote the above query to get the following output but it throws me with an Exception.

The desired output is:

```
email           |  client_ip    |  travelling_method | travelling_code| account_type
person1@abc.com |203.22.22.22   | Car                | car001         | true
person1@abc.com |203.22.22.22   | Jeep               | jeep001        | false
```

Appreciate if someone could help me out to point me out what im missing in my query. :)

Comment: Can you add error stack one more thing can you replace where with and in last of query

Answer (score 0):

Try writing " where " in right place like

```
SELECT table1.email, table1.client_ip, table1.travelling_method, table1.travelling_code, table2.account_type 
 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email WHERE 
 table1.client_ip = table2.client_ip 
 AND table1.travelling_code LIKE CONCAT('%' ,table2.trav_code, '%') and table1.email = 'person1@abc.com'
```

I did not test your query. If still face error then post with error message.

Comment: I tried your query but it still keeps throwing an ERROR: AnalyticsProcessorAdminServiceAnalyticsProcessorAdminExceptionException.